# Can --always-make not affect a sub-make?

Tags: gnu-make

Using GNU Make 4.1

#### Summary

I am calling a sub-make `b.mk` from a makefile `a.mk`.
`b.mk` is called to ensure that a sub-system is built.
Sometimes I want to force a target of `a.mk` to be remade:

```
make -f a.mk <target> --always-make
```

When I do this, `b.mk` also considers all targets out of date, but I don't want it to.

#### Failed remedy

I have tried using `make -f b.mk MAKEFLAGS=`, as suggested in the manual
[5.7.3 Communicating Options to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html), but with no luck.

Here is the gist of `a.mk`:

```
.PHONY: all
$(info ===> a.mk MAKEFLAGS: $(MAKEFLAGS))
all:
    $(MAKE) -f b.mk y MAKEFLAGS=
```

and `b.mk`:

```
$(info ===> b.mk MAKEFLAGS: $(MAKEFLAGS))
y: x
    cp $< $@
```

Now, even when `b.mk` would normally regard `y` as being up to date:

```
$ make -f b.mk y
===> b.mk MAKEFLAGS: 
make: 'y' is up to date.
```

... `y` is remade when `a.mk` is called with `--always-make (-B)`:

```
$ make -f a.mk --always-make
===> a.mk MAKEFLAGS: B
make -f b.mk y MAKEFLAGS=
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/matt/junk/make-b'
===> b.mk MAKEFLAGS: 
cp x y
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/matt/junk/make-b'
```

As you can see, the `B` flag appears in `a.mk`'s MAKEFLAGS, but not in those of `b.mk`.
However, `y` is remade by `b.mk`.

#### Questions

- Why?
- Is there a way around this?
- With GNU make I would expect that there's a very good reason for this behaviour. What is the reason?

#### Update: 2020-08-05

Why (on earth) would I want to do this?

In the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63231100/685715, there was a request to see an example of wanting to force a particular target to be remade, but without wanting sub-makes forced too.

Rather than invent something, here is an extract from the actual makefile which led to my question:

```
WWW_SVG := score.svg

%Score.app/$(WWW_SVG): %Score.svg | %Score.app/
    cd $(MUSIC_SCORE_PLAYER) && $(MAKE) -f $(MUSIC_SCORE_PLAYER_MAKEFILE) $(MUSIC_SCORE_PLAYER_TGT) MAKEFLAGS=
    cp $< $(MUSIC_SCORE_PLAYER_DIR)$(WWW_SVG)
    node $(MUSIC_SCORE_PLAYER_SVG_CONVERTER) > $@
```

The purpose of the rule is to create one SVG from another.
The new one mirrors the state of the SVG part of the DOM after a web application loads and modifies the original SVG.

- The first line of the recipe uses a sub-make to ensure that the web application is up to date, which it may not be as I am currently developing it. The web app is a separate project to the one with the makefile from which the above snippet was extracted.
- The second line copies the original SVG into the web app's deployment directory so that it can be loaded by the web app
- The third line calls a node script to launch the web app, extract the SVG from its DOM, and write it to stdout. This is then redirected to update the SVG target.

While I am testing, I want to be able to force the re-making of targets which have prerequisites that match `%FooScore/score.svg`, but without rebuilding the web application, *unless* it is out of date.

Of course, I could move the line that calls the sub-make so that it would be invoked just once, not once for every target that matches the rule. But that is an optimization, not a solution.

Comment: Try `$(MAKE)` instead of `make`. Reading the docs I come to the same conclusion. No special rule mentioned for -B so at the very least the behavior is undocumented.

Comment: @Andreas - you are right that I should be using `$(MAKE)` instead of `make`. I have updated the question, but this does not change the behaviour.

Comment: Ok, then I'd say it's time to file a bug.

Comment: @Andreas I expect that there are users who (perhaps unknowingly) depend on the current behaviour - e.g. use `MAKEFLAGS=` to clear out command line arguments, but still expect the `-B` to be passed to sub-makes. Perhaps it is a bug that `B` does not show up in the sub-make's MAKEFLAGS? Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63231100/685715) and its comments.

Looking at `a.mk` from the original question, one line needs to be changed:

```
.PHONY: all
$(info ===> a.mk MAKEFLAGS: $(MAKEFLAGS))
all:
    MAKEFLAGS=  $(MAKE) -f b.mk y    # This line has changed
```

It now uses `MAKEFLAGS` as an envirnoment variable instead of a command line parameter. See the comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63231100/685715) for why this makes a difference.

We now see that `-B` (`--always-make`) is not passed to the sub-make **and** that, unlike when `MAKEFLAGS` is passed as a command line varibale, the sub-make does not "always-make":

```
$ make -B -f a.mk 
===> a.mk MAKEFLAGS: B
MAKEFLAGS= make -f b.mk y
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/matt/junk/make-b'
===> b.mk MAKEFLAGS: w
make[1]: 'y' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/matt/junk/make-b'
```

The other difference here, compared to the output shown in the original question, is that the `-w` (`--print-directory`) flag is passed to the sub-make, which is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The point of "always build" is that all the parts of the build are invoked.  It wouldn't make sense for this to *not* be passed down to sub-makes.  In fact many makefiles have almost nothing happening at the top level makefile: they just invoke a set of sub-makes.  If "always build" were not passed down, it would serve little purpose.

Unfortunately your examples are all predicated on things working this way, and they don't.  In order to suggest a solution we'd need to see a more realistic example.  In particular, you say you want to force a specific target to be remade but in your examples above you don't show that.  What is the target that is to be remade?  How does it interact with the sub-make invocation of `b.mk`?

As a note I should say, you should *never* use `make` to invoke sub-makes.  You should *always* use `$(MAKE)` (or, equivalently, `${MAKE}`).

Comment: Good point re `$(MAKE)`. I am using it in my 'real' makefile, but forgot to put than in my minimal example, which I have now updated.

Comment: I understand that in most situations, one would want "always build" to be  passed to sub-makes. But I was surprised to find that I could not turn off this behaviour, even though https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html  hints that you can: "If you do not want to pass the other flags down, you must change the value of MAKEFLAGS, like this". I also found it mysterious that the `B` MAKEFLAG does disappear from the sub-make, and yet it still behaves in a `-B` way. I can find a workaround, by my curiousity was peeked.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide an example of what I'm actually doing, rather than a minimal working example that just reveals the bare bones of make's behaviour.

Comment: The fact that you can't turn it off could be a bug.  The reason for it is that the sub-make reads the value of `MAKEFLAGS` first, then parses the command line and resets the value to empty (that's why you don't see a value when you print it).  But the setting has already been applied so resetting MAKEFLAGS doesn't help.  Possibly make should first apply command-line variables, _then_ parse `MAKEFLAGS`.  But I'm not sure what other side-effects such a change would have.

Comment: If you want to override `MAKEFLAGS`, the safer way to do it is in the environment: instead of `$(MAKE) MAKEFLAGS=` try using `MAKEFLAGS= $(MAKE)` (don't forget the space there :) ).

Comment: Amazing! The environment variable suggestion works: `MAKEFLAGS=   $(MAKE)`. Thank you.
An interesting side effect is that the `w` flag (--print-directory) is now explicitly set in the sub-make (according to my `$(info $(MAKEFLAGS))`output), and that is fine. Whereas, with `MAKEFLAGS=` as a command-line variable, the sub-make behaved as if it were set, but it didn't show up in the `$(info)` output. (I won't ask how to turn off `-w` in a sub-make :) ).